# Twitter: Combine calls to Twitter from many follow buttons into one?

Tags: twitter, twitter-follow

I'd like to include many Twitter [follow buttons](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button) in one page, but each button makes a separate call to Twitter to check if the user is being followed. Is there a way to combine all of the calls into one, to reduce the number of requests made and improve performance?

Comment: Is there one button per user?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to have many users on the page.